# How can I monitoring the status of AWS DMS database migration tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-dms

Our team is trying to use AWS DMS to sync some data from AWS RDS to AWS Redshift

I can get status of database migration tasks from AWS console.
If everything goes well, the status will be **'Load complete, replication ongoing'**.
But when errors happened, it will become to **'Running with errors'**.

I have some tries to set a alerm which can send alerts to my chatroom when something went wrong.

1: create a error filter for DMS log group (not working well, sometimes error happened but task status is still **'Load complete, replication ongoing'**)

2: find a usable command in DMS aws-cli (no command response is include status 'Running with errors')

3: existed DMS cloudwatch metrics (can not find a usable metrics)

Comment: Have you considered the `aws dms describe-table-statistics` comand to check if any tablecstate report an error?

Comment: You can also use control table task settings : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TaskSettings.ControlTable.html